# DataTables Loading message not being displayed

Tags: datatables

I had no luck with other so answers on the matter so here I am. I populate the table with some MySQL data, it's never drawn until data is ready to show, and since the data is taking its time I'd like a message to pop. Here's the full code.

```js
function getData(startDate, endDate) {  
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getData",
        type: 'post',   
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false,         
        dataType: "json",       
        data : JSON.stringify({ startDate : startDate, endDate : endDate }),            
        complete: function(data){               
            $("#offline").dataTable({                                           
                "aaData": data.responseJSON[0],                     
                "bProcessing": true,                        
                "aoColumns": [                              
                    { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield1", "mDataProp": "field1"},
                    { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield2", "mDataProp": "field2"},
                    { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield3", "mDataProp": "field3"},
                    { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield4", "mDataProp": "field4",
                        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {                                               
                                    return data + ' %';
                                } 
                            }
                ],              
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sUrl": "/javascripts/i18n/dataTables.modified.json"
                },                  
                "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                "bSort": false,
                "bInfo" : false,                                
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false
            });
        }
    });
}
```

For what I've read I need to set `bProcessing` to true and to do something with the `sDom` parameter but I wasn't able to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the processing message isn't showing because by the time you initialise the datatable(in the ajax 'complete' callback), the data is already loaded so there's no need to show the processing message. If you init the datatable first and use sAjaxSource to load the data it will work as you expect:

```
var oTable = $("#offline").dataTable({                                           
    'bServerSide': true,
    'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
       aoData.push({ "name": "startDate", "value": $('#startDate').val() });
       aoData.push({ "name": "endDate", "value": $('#endDate').val() });
     },
     'sAjaxSource': "/getData",
    'bProcessing': true,                     
    "aoColumns": [                              
        { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield1", "mDataProp": "field1"},
        { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield2", "mDataProp": "field2"},
        { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield3", "mDataProp": "field3"},
        { "sWidth": "25%","sTitle": "Myfield4", "mDataProp": "field4",
            "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {                                               
                        return data + ' %';
                    } 
                }
    ],              
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "/javascripts/i18n/dataTables.modified.json"
    },                  
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo" : false,                                
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false
});
```

Note that I'm passing your start & end date params using `fnServerParams`, but you could also add them on to the end of the url:  `/getData?startDate=`...

Comment: Thanks Mark. But the call throws a 404 error. I don't get it since the url does exist. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the full url instead of just `/getData`?

Comment: same thing, a datatables pop un warning error with this http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Comment: can you browse to the url?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. I'm on a `node.js`/`express` modular route. This route has a couple of `.jade` files and an `index.js` file. Inside that `.js` file I have all my `app.get` and `app.post`, one of them is `app.post('/getData', function(req, res){...});` How to browse there?

Comment: If you use Firebug (or something similar) you'll be able to see the url POST in the 'Network' tab.

Comment: Thanks mark, the 404 error `http://localhost:1337/getData?sEcho=1&iColumns=4&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=-1&mDataProp_0=field1&mDataProp_1=field2&mDataProp_2=field3&mDataProp_3=field4&startDate=2014-06-01&endDate=2014-06-30&_=1405944726055` That's what comes, and it's shown as GET, when it's actually a POST.

Comment: and what happens if you paste that into you browser address bar & press return?

Comment: cannot GET /getData?sEcho... As stated in the original question, the ajax call works and data is being retrieved. This not-finding the url came when using `sAjaxSource`

Comment: I think `sAjaxSource` uses GET by default so maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I sorted the other issue so now I was able to check your solution and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One more thing of note...You must include the dom code "r" to the datatables creation script...

```
dom: "r",
processing: true,
```

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html